# PDF Generation Failed when first result of list does not match criteria

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, case, pdf, related-list

"PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid."

I have an apex data table to list cases related to a contract. However, I want to only display specific record types on the list. My current solution works fine, unless the most recent case (or first result of the list) is a different record type than specified. Then I get the above error.

It also works fine as a standard visualforce page, but rendered as a PDF, it fails.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? If this is Salesforce just being Salesforce, is there a workaround?

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" standardController="Contract">
    <apex:dataTable value="{!Contract.Claims__r}" var="claim" id="claimTableInfo" width="100%" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="claimRecordsTable" border="solid" cellpadding="5px">
        <apex:column rendered="{!if(claim.recordTypeID == '012b0000000Kr2VAAS','true','false')}" styleClass="claimRecordsTable" width="170px">
            <apex:outputText value="{!claim.CaseNumber}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column rendered="{!if(claim.recordTypeID == '012b0000000Kr2VAAS','true','false')}" styleClass="claimRecordsTable" width="170px">
            <apex:outputText value="{0,Date,dd/MM/yy}"><apex:param value="{!claim.Recevied_Date__c}" /></apex:outputText>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect the page to do weird things, because you're doing weird things. You're asking Visualforce to render *an entire column* based on every individual record in the list. `rendered` is only designed to work on a single value, not a list of items. I would expect it shouldn't be working without PDF mode, either. Instead, I would just render the table directly:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case Number</th>
            <th>Received Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!Contract.Claims__r}" var="claim" id="claimTableInfo" width="100%" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="claimRecordsTable" border="solid" cellpadding="5px">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!claim.RecordTypeId='012b0000000Kr2VAAS'}">
            <tr>
                <td class="claimRecordsTable" width="170">{!claim.CaseNumber}</td>
                <td class="claimRecordsTable" width="170">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,Date,dd/MM/yy}"><apex:param value="{!claim.Recevied_Date__c}" /></apex:outputText>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Managed to solve it by mixing in this with a custom controller extension. Thanks!